# What is an use case of flask flashing?

Tags: flask

> The flashing system basically makes it possible to record a message at
> the end of a request and access it on the next (and only the next)
> request

Please can I have an example wherein a msg recorded at the end of a request will need to be accessed in the next request?

Answer (score 0):

flashing is very useful for websites.

Let's say you have a login system on your website and you want to notify user after they logout, then you can simply add a flash message saying something like "You have been logged out!"

Everything works fine without flashing but it gives extra confirmation to the user and makes website more user-friendly.